# How to change bootstrap glyphicon color in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `glyphicon-ok` in my li element.Initially as per my requirement I am giving green to all glyphicon-ok like this

```
.glyphicon-ok {
    color: #41be47;
}
```

One li element is like the below

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#"  onclick="return getQuestions(this);"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;test
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" style="display: block;" ></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Now I want to change `glyphicon-ok` to white color when that particular is clicked.

So what should I write inside

```
function  getQuestions(id) {
}
```

I tried

```
function  getQuestions(id) {

$('span').find('.glyphicon-ok').css('color','#fff');
}
```

Comment: function  getQuestions(id) {
    id.addClass('class name');
}

Comment: Try color: #41be47 !important;

Comment: @HoangHieu I want to change the  glyphicon-ok color to white,

Comment: @Neophyte I tried your way but it did not work

Comment: try this:   id.style.color = 'while';

Comment: @HoangHieu did not work

Comment: follow this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221160/how-to-change-a-css-class-style-through-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really willing to do it through javascript:

First option, listens to click on the icon

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.glyphicon-ok').on("click", function(){
        $(this).css("color", "#FFF000");
    });
});
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Dk9/1/

Second option listens to click on the li element:
Add class to the li (not essential, but easier in bigger projectes):

```
<li class="active clickable">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.clickable').on("click", function(){
        $(this).find('.glyphicon').css("color", "#FFF000");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T9Dk9/2/

But I guess there will be a method in Bootstrap do define a 'clicked' color for links

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I am not clicking on glyphicon-ok but clicking on the li

Comment: @SpringLearner add an example of that scenario as well. But I would dig into bootstrap CSS to see if there's a way to define it through CSS.

Comment: your solution works,+1.Suppose if I have 3 li.I clicked on 1st li so it changes to yellow.Now when I click on the 2nd li then the 1st li should go to green.But this is not happening

Comment: @SpringLearner If you have multiple LI's and you want a click on one li to change the color of the second one, you indeed need some changes in the javascript. I suggest you add the complete html of the fiddlr to your situation and post the update link. Also, don't forget to accept my answer, since it has answered your initial question

Comment: Think it's worth pointing out here that this can all be done using css and JS is a bit unnecessary for changing the color of an icon.

Comment: @Guy I absolutely agree. Personally I would even prefer CSS. Suggested it multiple times. But the TS wants to have a JS solution.

Comment: @DennisHunink Yea saw that and facepalmed slightly :D

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the `color` property in the css. One of the major benefits of an icon **font** is that you can use font css properties on them. 
Using the `:focus` and `:active` selector to apply these styles would be a better solution than using javascript.

[Example](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/wqfct)

If you do decide to use javascript i would suggest using it only to add/remove a class rather than apply the styling itself.

Comment: Ok then tell me how to remove the color of glyphicon-ok

Comment: `color: transparent` or `color: #fff` if the background is white?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[element]').css({
    color:'#ffffff !important',
});
```

demo [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SXsuv/27/)

Comment: for my case I have to write glyphicon-ok in place of element?

Answer (score 0):

come on guys you must change class,

if you want that icon must be white alfer click add some class.

try it (on hover for example:)

```
$('span').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass("white");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass("white");
    }
});
```