How to detect a CSS class is active in or change CSS class name using Javascript
I have the following html codes:
    <li class="imagenav active">
      some codes go here
    </li>

Is there a way of checking if imagenav class is active or change CSS class using Javascript. for example:
    if imagenav is active {
      do some codes here ...
    }

Many thanks in advance.
Thank you for Barmar for advising how to check if a list has a class. However, in my case, I prefer to change CSS class using Javascript which makes it easier to manipulate my codes. So I have to add id into HTML codes. I want the left arrow to be active/disabled when the page is first loaded. Here are my fully working codes:
    <div id="active-leftarrow" class="imagenav">
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('active-leftarrow').className = 'imagenav disabled';
      </script>
    </div>

Many thanks

In JavaScript you can use if (element.classList.includes("active"))

In jQuery, if ($(".imagenav").hasClass("active"))

but that does not have a specific imagenav class; how would javascript know it refers to imagenav?

I assumed you set element first to the imagenav element. let element = document.querySelector(".imagenav")

Thanks I ll try that and give a feedback sortly.

It works well. But I have changed my mind to use javascript to change CSS class name instead which is easier to manipulate codes in my case. Look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221160/how-to-change-a-css-class-style-through-javascript
